# Is there any way to parse Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeometry to SVG?

Tags: c#, sql-server, svg

I have a Table in my database where on of the columns is of type "geometry".
I want to take the data contained in this column (polygons and circles) and convert them into something easily parse-able and rendered in HTML (preferably as SVG), but i cannot seem to be able to do it.

I have been able to extract GML and WKT from the database, but neither of these seem to get me closer to my goal without additional parsing on the front-end that will be prone to error. Are there any built-ins or third party librarys that are capable of doing this? Is there a simple conversion I can make that I am overlooking? I am at a loss to why this cant be done, as i would have thought this would be a useful tool others would need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is relatively easy to convert to `GeoJson` from `GEOMETRY` and `GEOGRAPHY` SQL types.

From there it is easier to convert to `SVG`.

**Edit:**

[NPM package for GeoJson to SVG converter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/geojson-to-svg)

[GitHub repo for another GeoJson to SVG converter](https://github.com/gagan-bansal/geojson2svg)

[SQL: Returning Spatial Data in GeoJson Format (part 1)](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlserverstorageengine/2016/01/05/returning-spatial-data-in-geojson-format-part-1/)

[SQL: Returning Spatial Data in GeoJson Format (part 1)](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlserverstorageengine/2016/01/13/returning-spatial-data-in-geojson-format-part-2/)

And the relevant SQL function from the second tutorial:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.geometry2json ( @geo GEOMETRY )
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
    BEGIN
        RETURN (
     '{' +
     (CASE @geo.STGeometryType()
     WHEN 'POINT' THEN
     '"type": "Point","coordinates":' +
     REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@geo.ToString(),'POINT ',''),'(','['),')',']'),' ',',')
     WHEN 'POLYGON' THEN 
     '"type": "Polygon","coordinates":' +
     '[' + REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@geo.ToString(),'POLYGON ',''),'(','['),')',']'),'], ',']],['),', ','],['),' ',',') + ']'
     WHEN 'MULTIPOLYGON' THEN 
     '"type": "MultiPolygon","coordinates":' +
     '[' + REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@geo.ToString(),'MULTIPOLYGON ',''),'(','['),')',']'),'], ',']],['),', ','],['),' ',',') + ']'
     WHEN 'MULTIPOINT' THEN
     '"type": "MultiPoint","coordinates":' +
     '[' + REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@geo.ToString(),'MULTIPOINT ',''),'(','['),')',']'),'], ',']],['),', ','],['),' ',',') + ']'
     WHEN 'LINESTRING' THEN
     '"type": "LineString","coordinates":' +
     '[' + REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@geo.ToString(),'LINESTRING ',''),'(','['),')',']'),'], ',']],['),', ','],['),' ',',') + ']'
     ELSE NULL
     END)
     +'}');
    END;
```

Comment: You say it is relatively easy, would you mind adding methods and/or tools required? Thanks.

Comment: Added links and the SQL for GEOMETRY to GeoJson.

Comment: Is there a way of converting svg into spatial queries?